# React dynamically create routes

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router

First things first is this possible to have 2 components on a page one displaying simple static markup but the second one in my parent is going to be a div that displays a link for each item in an array and if you click on it at the bottom of the div then data will be displayed for each one?

If this is possible are dynamic props as simple as performing .map inside the  element and printing out a route?

Will also add that I am receiving the following on my Router object but I installed react-router globally though it is also in my node_modules folder.

> 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'hashHistory'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

class DetailsComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
       // in here will map this.props.data and for each one print a route
       // the component for that route will be a DetailedViewComponent that
       // that takes in the data in the props and renders it
       // so i might need a link? in this render method aswell?
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailsComponent ;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spoke to some more senior react developers and they said what I was after was [npm package Component-Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/component-router) I haven't got back onto the project just yet but will post full code once completed :)

Answer (score 3):

[`React Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) params can be used to render content dynamically

ie. `<Route path="/dynamicroute/:id" component={DynamicComponent}/>` will provide an `id` param that can be retrieved via `props.match.params` inside  `<DynamicComponent/>`

Comment: my question has been updated please take another look

Comment: Probably a few things to still go through but getting "You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>" that but definitely progress!

Comment: Ended up adding a Router around it and got this instead "TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" maybe didnt install something correctly?

Comment: Not sure how to check it didn't update my package.json automatically but is in node_modules. Also will having a router at the base of my app mess up the components that are not going to change at all? that are static and are on the same level as the component that needs routing?

Comment: quick check in one of the files in node_modules and found this but not sure if its right _id": "react-router@4.2.0",

Comment: Yep that works :) Put a switch inside it too, so should I now just follow that tutorial link you sent before on switchs? I will update my code in initial post shortly with where im at if thats the case